# How to initialise SparkSession in Spark 3.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been trying to learn Spark & Scala, and have an environment setup in IntelliJ.

I'd previously been using SparkContext to initialise my Spark instance successfully, using the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark._    
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "SparkTest")
```

When I tried to start loading .csv data in, most information I found used `spark.read.format("csv").load("filename.csv")` but this requires initialising a `SparkSession` object using:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .master("local")
  .builder()
  .appName("Test")
  .getOrCreate()
```

But when I tried to use this, there doesn't seem to be any `SparkSession` in `org.apache.spark._` in my version of Spark 3.x.

As far as I'm aware, the use of `SparkContext` is the Spark 1.x method, and `SparkSession` is Spark 2.x where `spark.sql` is built-in to the SparkSession object.

My question is whether I'm incorrectly trying to load `SparkSession` or if there's a separate way to approach initialising Spark (and loading .csv files) in Spark 3?

Spark version: 3.3.0

Scala version: 2.13.8

Comment: For troubleshooting, try creating Maven type project in IntelliJ and add Spark dependency in POM file.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde that's solved the issue, thank you!! I hadn't realised I'd need to specify each Spark dependency in the POM file (build.sbt for me as I built using SBT), which then gives me access to SparkSession (although spark.read still not working, but that's another issue!).


If you want to post an answer then I can accept it!

Comment: Added as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Maven type project then try adding dependencies to the POM file. Otherwise, for the sake of troubleshooting, create a new Maven type project, add dependencies and check whether you are still having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your build.sbt file to include spark-sql lib module:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.0",
```

(change version accordingly)

and, reload/rebuild your project.

Then, in your code file, where you try to create SparkSession,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

Hope this helps someone!